# Numeric input in C++ with trailing chars

Tags: c++, double, cin

I need to fetch user input from `std::cin` into a variable of type `double`. This is in the context of complex numbers, so it often happens to have a number input as `5i` or `5.4565i`.

Consider the following code in the `main()` function:

```
while (true) {
    double c;
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << c << "\n\n";
}
```

Here's what happens:

```
In: 0.45
Out: 0.45
// OK

In: 5 0.45
Out: 5

0.45
// OK

In: 0.45i
Expected out: 0.45
Acutal out: 0

0

0...
```

I'm guessing this is because It's not recognizing `0.45i` as a `double`. So how can I correctly fetch the value `0.45` from `0.45i`, ignoring the trailing `i`?

Comment: Why not read into string first? Then iterate each character of the string to test if it is not a digit and remove it (excluding the leading - and the period). What is left can be converted to a double for display.

Comment: Not sure if that helps: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt

Comment: Actually, the output is correct, because an imaginary number is 0 on the real axis.  I do realize that this does not answer your question (already given by Yan Zhou).

Comment: @stefaanv Yes of course, but since I'm implementing a `struct complex` I want to fetch the imaginary part of the input number, and store it as such.

Comment: And I guess that when given the time, you already managed to implement the read.  Just one small question: are you aware of the already existing [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) (which wouldn't have helped with reading in the number)

Comment: @stefaanv Actually no I wasn't familiar with it, thanks. But I still want to implement it myself here - it's more of a learning exercise than a serious application :)

Comment: Best of luck, it is a good excercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read a string first and then convert to double,

```
$ cat ans.cpp 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    double dbl;
    while (std::cin >> str) {
        dbl = std::strtod(str.data(), NULL);
        std::cout << dbl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

First you read each white space separated string into `str`. The `strtod` function will try to get as many as characters to form a floating point literate, including hex float. It returns the double parsed from this part of the string. The second parameter can be a `char *` pointer, which point to one pass the last character that is parsed. It is useful if you do not want to simply discard the trailing characters. It is ignored if it is null.

Comment: Thank you! `strtod` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can test the state of the input string. If input has *failed*, just get the offending token in a string and proceed. For example:

```
double d;

for(;;) {
    std::string dummy;
    std::cout << "Input :";
    std::cin >> d;
    if (std::cin.fail()) {          // was input numeric?
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> dummy;
        if (dummy == "END") break;  // out of the infinite loop...
        std::cout << "Non numeric: >" << dummy << "<" << std::endl;

    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Numeric: " << d << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading `std::string` and then parsing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be you take input as a string and then analyse it character by character using a for loop. And then convert it into the double while ignoring the i.You could divide the string into three parts i.e integer part, decimal part and i.

And for separating these you could use conditions like if(c[i]=='.') and if(c[i]=='i').